# power electronics inquiry

Tags: rectifier

I want to ask you about the following graph exactly the added resistance after the rectifier and the filter. Is it ok to add this resistance to make sure that the filtered voltage will occur on the resistance and then goes to the buck converter?

note: I don't mean the load resistance, I mean the resistance in the middle of the graph.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! In electronic engineering, please don't refer to "resistance in the middle of the graph", use their designators. Do you mean R4?

Answer (score 1):

In my view it is necessary in that circuit as a bleeder resistor.it will be useful to discharge the excess charge stored in filter capacitor after the diode bridge rectifier....

Comment: thank you for ur help...really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, this resistor is usually used for discharging some capacitance in order for example to prevent exposing energized pins. However, your resistor is way too small and it adds a lot of power loss. Usually this resistor is in the range of Mega Ohms in order to reduce this power loss.